# Click on a right click menu

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to click on a button from a right click menu with nightwatch.

I have tried that:

```
.moveToElement('#nightwatch', 10, 10)
.mouseButtonClick('rigth')
```

But then, I need to click on a button from this menu, but I cannot. The menu is open and close inmediately, don't pause until I click on the button.

Anybody knows why?

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried with other websites, but the same problem remain:

```
browser.waitForElementVisible('body', 5000)
browser.moveToElement('#tsf', 10, 10)
browser.mouseButtonClick('right')
browser.pause(8000)
```

With www.google.ch

But the right click menu never appears.

Comment: You have misspelled "right" in the second line.  is that the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortounately that is not the problem, I have also tried to put 2 instead of right, but it do nothing. I think that the right click panel is never shown

Comment: If you can provide us with a link to the site, or a at least some of the relevant html, that would help us to help you.

Comment: I edited the post, but it doesn't work with any website.

Comment: I have good experience with `selenium` and `chromedriver`. After a few `selenium.webdriver.chrome.options` you can perform clicks with 'webdriver.find_element_by_id("ID").click()'. I that an alternative for you?

Comment: Click will work fine, right click doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Not the only thing in nightwatch. I'm beginning to question why that 'framework' has even been released.